# Pycharm is not showing installed packages : PyBluez

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, package, pybluez

I have installed pybluez (a python package) using `pip install pybluez`, but pybluez is not listed in my package list. My python version is `python2.7` and I installed `pycharm-2018.1.1` on my PC running Ubuntu 16.04.

I can see pybluez is installed using `pip list` 
[image]

I have also installed pybluez in pycharm and it shows that pybluez is successfully installed. 
[image]

However pybluez is still not listed in the pycharm packages list.

[image]

This is the error I see when running the program from pycharm.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I notice that you have several versions of Python installed.  The `pip` command you ran was for Python 2.  The Python shown in Pycharm is a Python 3 virtual environment.

Try `env/bin/python -m pip list` to verify that the package is there.  If not you can do `env/bin/python -m pip install <package name>` to ensure that the package gets installed to the right place.  Lastly, be sure on Pycharm that you are selecting installing to the right Python interpreter!

`cd ~/PyCharm/Projects/Bluetooth && env/bin/python -m pip install pybluez`

Comment: Thanks @snakes_on_a_keyboard. Sir . it is showing no such file.

Comment: vikas@vikas:/$ env/bin/python -m pip list
bash: env/bin/python: No such file or directory
vikas@vikas:/$ env/bin/python -m pip install pybluez
bash: env/bin/python: No such file or directory

Comment: what should i do now.

Comment: sorry, I should've been more specific... you need to `cd` to that directory first.  `cd ~/PyCharm/Projects/Bluetooth/` then run that command